# SQL: select count with min rows in table

Tags: sql, select, count, h2, min

I have a table:

```
TABLE employee (
    ID               bigint,
    name             varchar,
    department bigint
);
```

I would like to find a department that has minimal employees. (Count of rows in this table)
I believe this would require a HAVING statement with a nested sub-query, any help would be much appreciated.
I am using H2 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by department and get the count of users in each department, order by the count and select top 1?

```
SELECT TOP 1
[department],
COUNT(*) AS [NoOfEmployees]
FROM [employee]
GROUP BY [department]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
```